# Как отключить названия рек и озер на Яндекс-Карте?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Проблема в том, что при использовании английской локали en_RU, не все названия переведены правильно, например на карте можно увидеть proliv или zaliv. Как можно отключить название рек, проливов и пр. водных ресурсов?

Comment: Никак, Яндекс отдает готовые картинки карт. Все, чем можно управлять, он рисует поверх карт. И вообще - чужие данные не ваша проблема!

Comment: К сожалению, наша проблема, карты должны работ идеально, как для иностранных пользователей, так и для российских и названия в транслите просто недопустимы

Comment: Вместо яндекса показывайте иностранным гостям гугл карты. Либо обратитесь в ТП Яндекса, раз это косяк с их стороны (Яндекса в смысле)